# Javascript/Jquery export to Excel in Internet Explorer 10+

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, internet-explorer, export-to-excel

I've done lots of research and have come to a conclusion that its probably not possible to Export data to Excel using only the client side via Javascript/Jquery for Internet Explorer 10+ because it doesn't support the uri object.

Using only the client side, does anyone provide alternatives to handle a situation like this in IE?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-output.html  could export to a csv file

Comment: A demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/fucqhe26/1/

Comment: @RobertRozas Unfortunately, your second link needs php to be able to download to a csv.  Was looking for a client side examples in javsacript only.  Thanks!

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/ru0h1hbg/1/

Comment: @RobertRozas Your last example works well with both Chrome and Firefox but not in IE 10 which really sucks lol.

Comment: This is classic...which version of IE anyway??

Comment: @RobertRozas IE10+ seems to be broken and I think its because the support for uri

Comment: @Larbear IE only supports a few types for that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897(v=vs.85).aspx :(

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same task and the solution I came with was this one:

```
function exportTable(myTable, filename) {
//IE
if (isIE()) {
    csvData = myTable;
    if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
        var blob = new Blob([csvData], {
            type: "text/html"
        });
        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
    }
} //other browser
else {
    window.open("data:application/vnd.ms-excel," + encodeURIComponent(myTable));
}}
```

Then called it in a way you like, something like:

```
    $("#myButtonId").click(function (e) {
        exportTable($('#myTableId').html(), 'myFilename.xls');
    });
```

NB: I did not implement the filename option for other browsers.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

if uri is not working then use **blob**.Its working fine in IE 10 also.
in place of URI use blob its working fine.
Use below code

CSV is your data

```
var blob = new Blob([CSV], { type: 'text/csv' });
    if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName + '.csv');
    }
```